# Ajax call does not work when i add a custom route. Why does that happen?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have this controller:

```
public class StandingsController : Controller
{
    public ViewResult Index(int id)
    {

    }

    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult GetStage(int stage, int leagueid)
    {

    }
}
```

Ajax call:

```
 $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("GetStage", "Standings")',
            type: 'POST',
            data: { stage: currentStage, leagueid:leagueid },
            success: function (data) {
                    .............
```

I make an ajax request after page loads.
All i want is to change the url from `http://localhost/MyApp/Standings/Index/3` to `http://localhost/MyApp/Standings/3`. 
I added a custom route as follows:

```
 routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
 routes.RouteExistingFiles = false;
            routes.MapRoute(null, "Standings/{id}", new { controller = "Standings", action = "Index" });
 routes.MapRoute("Default", "{controller}/{action}/{id}", new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

but now i get an exception when making ajax call:

```
   The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ViewResult Index(Int32)' in 'MyApp.Controllers.StandingsController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
```

I don't understand what has ajax call to do with that id parameter from the ViewResult.
I really need some help with this. Thanks.

Comment: how does your ajax call look like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is expecting an id. Try either this:

```
url: '@Url.Action("GetStage", "Standings", new { id = 1 })',
```

...or this:

```
routes.MapRoute(null, "Standings/{id}", 
    new { controller = "Standings", action = "Index" }
    new { id = UrlParameter.Optional, });
```